# 'Unknown function sum called' error when trying to create a calculated field in tableau

Tags: ssas, tableau-api

I'm connecting to a SSAS data source from Tableau, and I'm having the following problem:

When I tried to create a calculated field in tableau, it gave me the "Unknown function sum called" error. I was doing a calculation as simple as this:

sum([Test Score])/sum([Score Count])

When using an Excel connection, the sum function works just fine. Is this some limitation of working with SSAS from Tableau?

Thanks ahead for any help!

Answer (score 5):

- [Understanding Functional Differences Between OLAP and Relational Data Source Connections](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/functional-differences-olap-relational)

> When connected to a cube, aggregation functions such as SUM(), AVG()
>   and similar are not available in the Tableau calculation editor [...]
>   the aggregations have already occurred in the cube, and cannot be
>   further aggregated. Note that you can also use Tableau Table
>   Calculations to perform post-OLAP aggregation operations on the
>   cell-level results from the cube.